# Character encoding: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF5fi S\xE1...' for column

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, character-encoding

I'm writing a spring-mvc jpa application to a legacy database. The character set of the database tables are iso-8859-2 (latin2). This cannot change for legacy reasons.

The database is mysql 5.5. The jpa implementation is hibernate 4.

The fields in the database can contain accented characters, like "áéíöőüű" etc.
When I try to merge the object, updating the database, I get an

```
SQLException: Incorrect string value : '\xF5fi S\xE1...' for column"
```

for a value "Petőfi Sándor".

The views are jsp-s, and I set the encoding to ISO-8859-2:

```
<meta charset="ISO-8859-2">
```

and the characters are displaying right, (well in the input fields are written with html special chars, for example

```
 &Aacute; instead of Á
```

but they are displaying fine.

I've looked at similar problems here, but did not find a solution. I would really appreciate if someone would know the solution. I'm in a pickle right now.

**Edit:**
Relevant parts from the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `cimek` (
...
`name` varchar(30) COLLATE latin2_hungarian_ci NOT NULL,
...
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4040
 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin2 COLLATE=latin2_hungarian_ci
```

Only the accented characters ő and ű are causing trouble.

Comment: Can you post the table and column definition? The database should accept `\xF5`.

Comment: The entire table definition is too long, but I will add the relevant parts as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

characterEncoding=ISO-8859-2

in your jdbc driver init

jdbc:mysql://location/dbname?characterEncoding=ISO-8859-2

Comment: I've changed the connection string in my persistence.xml file: name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
    value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull;characterEncoding=ISO-8859-2"   But I got the same error message